# Авторизация/идентификация в веб-приложении с помощью RFID-ключа

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите, как организовать авторизацию в веб-приложении с помощью RFID-ключа? К примеру, есть сервер, как котором исполняется приложение, и терминал, как котором открыт браузер и через который пользователь взаимодействует с ИС (веб-приложением). Пользователь вводит данные в систему, и по окончании ему нужно подтвердить свою личность, идентифицировать себя. К компьютеру подключен RFID-считываель, пользователь подносит карту, специальное приложение считывает данные с карты, а что дальше? Веб-клиент (браузер) должен получить считанные данные и передать их на сервер для авторизации, как организовать такую передачу?

Comment: Данные со считывателя хоть **каким-нибудь** способом уже научились доставать?

Comment: нет, RFID-считывателя тоже нет, я пока лишь прорабатываю варианты. Если веб-клиент в принципе не может взаимодействовать с устройствами, то какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Если с устройством может взаимодействовать система хоть каким-либо способом, этот способ с вероятностью ~100% можно выставить в виде веб-сервера. Например, с помощью [`websocketd`](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) можно превратить stdin/stdout процесса в вебсокет. А он из браузера уже доступен! ...если получится к нему подключиться.